# Does Ubuntu SDK include entire Qt toolchain?

Tags: qt, ubuntu-sdk

Does the Ubuntu SDK include all of Qt, or only a subset?

If I have existing (non-UI) components/libraries developed under Qt, can I use them in a Ubuntu/Unity/Ubuntu Touch application?

Generally, for sophisticated non-UI components of an Ubuntu application, for which JavaScript is not appropriate, is the recommended platform Qt, vanilla C++, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu SDK QML page http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/overview/ gives instruction to install the SDK from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ppa which states:

> This PPA provides Qt 5, Ubuntu UI Toolkit, Qt Creator and more for
>   various Ubuntu versions. It also provides some Qt modules that are not
>   part of Qt 5 - qtsensors, qt3d, qtlocation, qtfeedback,
>   qtconnectivity, qtsystems, qtpim, qtwayland. Those modules are just
>   snapshots and prone to any changes, but may be used for testing.

IMHO if a framework/library provides the/some functionality you need and you think it will save development effort without any obvious side effects (maintainability, portability, performance, ease of install on target platforms) then it is logical to use a framework.

Mark Shuttleworth's (pre touch) stance on frameworks http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/568  :

> Ease of use, and effective integration, are key values in our user
>   experience. We care that the applications we choose are harmonious
>   with one another and the system as a whole. Historically, that has
>   meant that we’ve given very strong preference to applications written
>   using Gtk, because a certain amount of harmony comes by default from
>   the use of the same developer toolkit. That said, with OpenOffice and
>   Firefox having been there from the start, Gtk is clearly not an
>   absolute requirement. What I’m arguing now is that it’s the values
>   which are important, and the toolkit is only a means to that end. We
>   should evaluate apps on the basis of how well they meet the
>   requirement, not prejudice them on the basis of technical choices made
>   by the developer.

Comment: It's certainly logical, but I'm specifically wondering what route Canonical is pushing.  Does the company envision that Ubuntu native applications would be written entirely under Qt?

Comment: epl, not whilst Unity has it foundations under GTK. I will dig the quote out later, but Mark Shuttleworth has stated Ubuntu is framework agnostic (it ships with XUL, QT and GTK). I have updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I am able to run a GTK, or more generally, an X application under Ubuntu just as under any other Linux flavor.  But the literature suggests that Canonical has a vision that developers will write applications specifically for Ubuntu taking advantage of particular features such as mobile convergence.  I am addressing this class of applications.  The literature says I can choose either Qt or HTML5, both with Ubuntu-only enhancements, for my UI development.  But what is allowed or recommended for components lower down on the stack, such as libraries?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't guess that GTK is feasible for Ubuntu Touch applications, so this is also a consideration.